# rails find object by subset of associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two main models `Product` and `Resource`. Products have many resources (which are required for their manufacture) and a Resource could be used in the production of many products, so I have a ProductResource` join table.

```rb
class ProductResource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :resource
end
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_resources
  has_many :resources, :through => :product_resources
end
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_resources
  has_many :products, :through => :product_resources
end
```

Let's say I then have 4 products (p1, p2, p3 & p4) and 3 resources (r1, r2 & r3) and via product_resources they are associated like this;

```
p1.resources #=> [r1]
p2.resources #=> [r1, r2]
p3.resources #=> [r1, r2, r3]
p4.resources #=> [r1, r3]
```

So this says that p2 for example needs resources r1 and r2 for it to be produced.
What I want is to have a query where I can say: if I have x resources, which products can I make.  In otherwords I want to be able to select the products which require **all or a subset** of a given set of resources, but which don't require any other resources.

For example I might want to find which products could be made given resources r1 and r2; and that should return p1 and p2. Or a query for resources r1 and r3, which should return just p4. If I queried for just r2 then it shouldn't return anything as there aren't any products that can be made with just r2. If I looked for products which could be made given r1, r2 & r3, then it should return all 4 products

One way I attempted this was to use `Set` like this:

```rb
available_resources = Set.new(Resource.where(:name => ['r1', 'r2']))
Product.all.select{|product| Set.new(product.resources).subset?(available_resources) }
```

That produces the desired results, but is clearly the wrong way to approach this and is extremely slow (as there are thousands of products and resources).

I also have tried like this, where I first select the resources which are **not** available, and then select product_resources for those resources and return the product_ids which require the unavailable resources and finally exclude those ids from the select on Product.

```rb
not_available = Resource.where("name not in (?)", ['r1','r2']).pluck(:id)
excluded_product_ids = ProductResource.select(:product_id).where(:resource_id => not_available).distinct.pluck(:product_id)
products = Product.where.not(:id => excluded_product_ids)
```

That is faster, but still pretty slow (>3000ms).

Is there a better way to approach finding an object which has all **or a subset** of a given set of associated objects over a HABTM association?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem, and there probably won't be one simple solution.

So - if it were just one resource the solution would be easy:

```
my_resource.products
```

But because it's a set of >= 1 resources it's less easy.
I'd start to approach it from here:

```
product_ids = ProductResource.where(:resource_id => my_resources).pluck(:product_id)
Product.find(product_ids)
```

The above is only a start, because it'd pull out all products that have 1 of, but not all of the required resources, so you may need to refine it with ruby eg:

```
my_resource_ids = my_resources.pluck(:id)
product_ids = ProductResource.where(:resource_id => my_resource_ids).pluck(:product_id)
products = Product.find(product_ids).select{|pr| my_resource_ids.all?{|rid| pr.resource_ids.include?(rid) } }
```

It's a bit uglier, but it refines down the set of products, then refines it further to those that contain all the resources...

Note: I'd be fairly confident that there's a way to encapsulate all this into a single SQL query - which would be the quickest way to go... but my SQL-fu is not good enough to do that for now... but you can often approach a solution like that incrementally.

Comment: Thanks for your approach. if I change your last line to 
`products = Product.where(:id => product_ids).select{|pr| Set.new(pr.resource_ids).subset?(Set.new(my_resource_ids))}` 
then that deals with the need for the products having all or a subset of the resources and is much faster than my first example using `Set`. 
But yes I'm certain there is a single SQL query solution to this but it's beyond my SQL-fu too!

Comment: my second example should deal with it too, no need for using Sets and subsets (you wanted an alternative that was more Railsy right?) :)

Comment: the difficulty with my requirement is I need Products which need all or a subset of the given resources, but no others. unless I'm missing something your solution returns products that use each of the given resources but may also use others too. This gives me the same result as your solution but is even faster. `products = Product; resource_ids.each{|rid| products = products.where(:id => ProductResource.where(:resource_id => rid).pluck(:product_id)) }` my trouble is in needing products that use all or subset of given resources and no others, and needing it to be fast!

Comment: The second line does that... my third line was intended to then select out the products that had all of the required resources... but I guess I didn't have the "or any subset" part in there... so yeah. it's a messy problem :)